# Receiving error "Select statements included within a function cannot return data to a client"

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, select

Receiving an error when attempting to use a Select statement in a function. The error states:

> Msg 444, Level 16, State 2, Procedure JDE_GetWhereClause_test, Line 26
>   Select statements included within a function cannot return data to a client.

Any ideas?

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[JDE_GetWhereClause_test]
(
@tablename as varchar
)
RETURNS varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
-- Declare the return variable here
Declare @ResultVar as varchar(max)

-- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here

set @tablename = 'F0101'
Declare @Sql nvarchar(max)
Declare my_cur cursor for
    SELECT fsuser FROM dbo.JDE_ExRowSecurity where fsuser = fsuser;

Declare @fsuser as nchar(15)
open my_cur;
fetch next from my_cur;
while @@fetch_status = 0
   begin
      fetch next from my_cur into @fsuser;    
      set @ResultVar += ',' + @fsuser;
   end;
close my_cur;
deallocate my_cur;

-- Return the result of the function
RETURN @ResultVar
END
```

Comment: By the way, you might swap the second `fetch next` statement with `set @ResultVar ...` as you skip over the first row and use the last row twice

Comment: Which is line 26 though. Also as per if i compare the syntax as its similar somewhat to oracle idk why you have begin after opening the cursor it should be before

Answer (score 16):

Try playing with something like...

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[JDE_GetWhereClause_test]
(
@tablename as varchar
)
RETURNS varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
  -- Declare the return variable here
  Declare @ResultVar as varchar(max)

  -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here

  set @ResultVar = (select STUFF((SELECT ',', fsuser as [text()]
                    FROM dbo.JDE_ExRowSecurity 
                    FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') as blah)

  -- Return the result of the function
  RETURN @ResultVar
END
```

`select 'Answer is: '+[dbo].[JDE_GetWhereClause_test]('whatever')`

Comment: hmm; I have a fairly complex select I was doing...the one I prsented here is a simple version. Anyways I'm going to switch to a stored procedure rather tha function since the return is a single large varchar field....Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Found this [MSDN article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/479cb04a-efdc-47bd-b0b9-9d20274477fa/error-select-statements-included-within-a-function-cannot-return-data-to-a-client?forum=sqlgetstarted) helpful and it resolved my issue:

```
RETURN (SELECT GETDATE());
```

Returning values directly from a select statement, avoiding variable.

Comment: these parentheses solved my problem. but why?